# Concatenating a string in a querystring of a <a> link in c# created through asp.net

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink, asp.net, concatenation

I can already send something in the querystring:

```
<a href='Exibe.aspx?var='lalala''>
```

but I'd like to send a string instead of lalala, and when i try to concatenate normally in the response.write with "+" signs, it just doesn't. it creates the url only with the part before the "+".

Facts:

- the string has a value
- I can concatenate it with other string and it works
- I can use the querystring with something I write

Thank you

UPDATE: code that doesn't work:

```
responde.write("<a href='Exibe.aspx?nome='" + nome(0) + "''> click here </a>");
```

Code that works but doesn't do what I want (sends "VALUE" not my string)

```
responde.write("<a href='Exibe.aspx?nome='VALUE''> click here </a>");
```

I'm really new at this.. sorry

Comment: You'll need to add a code sample of what you're trying to do in C#--it's imposible to tell what's going wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx) or are you looking for something to build the Uri like [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) ? Either way you should be able to google up some examples.

Comment: Thank you!  used HttpUtility.UrlEncode !
i'm really new at this, and i'd like to make it clear that i'm not asking anything i haven't googled about.. thanks again =)

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use a hyperlink server control? That way you have full control over the link element from you're code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>

HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "http://whereever.com/Default.aspx?Blah=whatever";
```

Comment: i'm creating this link at runtime.. if i do that it won't render as a link

Comment: I would personally think this method would be more valid for creating a link at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Also, with query strings you dont need to use quotation marks around each parameter.

This:

```
response.write("<a href='Exibe.aspx?nome=VALUE'> click here </a>");
```

Will pass the string "VALUE" through.